# QWebSocket from QTcpSocket

Tags: qt, websocket, qt5, qtwebsockets

I've written a small web server using QTcpServer, etc... It works fine so I wanted to get a bit further and implement Qt's WebSocket functionality. I want the WebSocket-Server to be reachable on the same port as my web server (due to limitations at my clients network).

My WebSocket-Server should be accessible at `/admin/socket` so I need a way to 'upgrade' a **QTcpSocket** *(accessible from the request handler for `/admin/socket`)* to a **QWebSocket**. QWebSocket has this functionality in [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebsockets.git/tree/src/websockets/qwebsocket.cpp#n313) constructor which is used by [this](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebsockets.git/tree/src/websockets/qwebsocketserver_p.cpp#n459) upgrade method in QWebSocketServerPrivate but it is all private and only used internally by the QWebSocketServer.

Is there a way to achieve what I described above? Do I have to implement my own WebSocket handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the requisite files from Qt's sources into your project, wrap the `QWebSocket` into a namespace so it won't clash with Qt's own, and make the constructor non-private. That's the only way to achieve that without writing a lot of your own code, and without invoking undefined behavior.

To use your type, make it visible via `using`; it will hide the Qt's `::QObject` then:

```
#include <QtCore>

namespace Foo { class QObject {}; }

int main() {
   using Foo::QObject;

   //         ours vvvvvvv        Qt's vvvvvvv
   Q_ASSERT(sizeof(QObject) < sizeof(::QObject));
}
```

Qt comes with a source code for a reason: you're supposed to use it when it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can also use `QWebSocketServer` with your own web server. You should not use `listen` of this `QWebSocketServer` because your own server is already listening on some port. Instead you simply call `handleConnection` of this `QWebSocketServer` instance and pass the `QTcpSocket` from some request instead of letting the request be handled by your own server.

The problem is that `QWebSocketServer::handleConnection` expects that no data has been read from the `QTcpSocket` in order to access the TCP request method, URL and headers. But since you do not want to pass *all* sockets to the `QWebSocketServer`, you need to `peek` the data from the `QTcpSocket`, make your decision (handle by your own server or let `QWebSocketServer` handle it) e.g. by searching for `Upgrade: websocket` (case insensitive) or by examining the URL. Then you can either pass the `QTcpSocket` to your `QWebSocketServer` instance or execute your own handler for normal HTTP responses. In case you already fully read the HTTP header by using `peek`, you can simply call `skip` on the socket in the latter case.